# embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.startChat doesn't work

Tags: liveagent, chat, embedded-services

I have been using embedded service for a while, I wanted to hide the standard button and start the chat with some custom button and for that I tried to use below code snippent. However, it gives me error all the time as `Cannot read property "startChat" of undefined`. If I print the object embedded_svc in the console, it comes fine. However, embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI gives an error. Can you please help what may have gone wrong?

```js
embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.startChat({
            directToAgentRouting: {
            buttonId: “573xx0000000000”,
            //userId: “”,
            fallback: true}, extraPrechatInfo: [], extraPrechatFormDetails: []});
```

Comment: Your error message is a very common one in working with JavaScript. At the time you're invoking `startChat`, `liveAgentAPI` is not defined. JavaScript is *case sensitive* so be sure you don't need to use `liveagentAPI` instead, which is what appears in Salesforce's documentation.

Comment: Hi @nbrown Thanks for response. I agree to what. you said. I tried using liveagentAPI, liveagentapi and just liveagent as well. However, nothing seems to work fine. I feel there is some dependency that I might be missing here, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I have tested different browsers, in firefox and safari the chat session is preserved, and it keeps opening the chat window even if I change the page or refresh the page, in chrome this functionality does not work well, and I have not been able to find the reason.

Chrome 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (arm64)
Firefox 107.0 (64-bit)
Safari 16.1 (17614.2.9.1.13, 17614)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).